# Adding google analytic for Salesforce tabs & pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component

I am trying to add Google analytic for custom made visualforce page and a tab. Do you guys know, is it possible or is there any other way to I can track?

Thanks

Comment: See links from [embed Analytics code in Visualforce page?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/forcecom-toolkit-for-google-analytics/n00LHfwCrjI).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible.  Just put the code from GA in script tags on a VF page.

For added fun, make it a VF component with an attribute so you can throw it on any custom page you make with just

Bonus points: Think through how you want to handle sandbox hits and testing the GA stuff...we used a custom setting to store the ga property so that we could change it in sandboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can use google analytics on custom made VisualForce page to track various events on the page. To provide you with a deep understanding this link will surely help you.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_site_googleAnalyticsTracking.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_analytics_tracking_code.htm&language=en_US

Still if you require any help then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. may be it will help for ya,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_site_googleAnalyticsTracking.htm