# Google Analytics - Visualforce page

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to use Google Analytics in **internal** Visualforce pages?

My VF page isn't exposed as a Force.com site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post on the [Google Analytics Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-analyticsjs/pTOxyG-Lqk0) the answer is a yes.

> Internal pages aren't a problem at all.
>
> All you do to track user interaction is send data to Google Analytics. Google Analytics does not need to send anything back, so it doesn't matter if the pages are internal or not.
>
> In fact, the pages don't even have to exist. If you send a pageview to Google Analytics with a spelling mistake, Google will happily accept it.

This [relevant question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81698/adding-google-analytic-for-sales-force-tabs-pages/81958) provides some details on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe yes you can use. If you are able to access the GA JS files you can use GA. You can also create a VF component for easy implementation. I think you may have to use My Domain for a fully qualified domain name (I am not sure about it).